# Creating / Editing a post from within site template

Tags: posts, templates, dashboard

I am developing a website that will allow multiple users to author short posts (Kind of like a job board) and I want to know how they can author or edit these posts from within the site template (Ie; without having to enter the dashboard).

Any advice or points in the right direction would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Font-End Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/). Or you can try some of these. [8 WordPress Plugins that Enable Posting and Editing From the Front-End](http://wpmu.org/8-wordpress-plugins-that-enable-posting-and-editing-from-the-front-end/)

I have never used any of these plugins, so I cannot say as to how well they will perform.

Comment: Thanks man I found "Post from site" plugin worked perfectly for what I needed.